# Tired of Restarting Eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse, performance, android-resources, r.java-file

As the title says, I m having problems with eclipse every now and then. To list few,

1. Missing `R` (the most frequent issue)
2. Conversion to Dalvik format failed with error 1
3. Cannot find resource

etc..

I tried many solutions already on SO, [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2680827/conversion-to-dalvik-format-failed-with-error-1-on-external-jar) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4842611/r-file-is-missing-android) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7649357/missing-r-java-file-even-though-project-cleaned) as well. However the issue still persisted.

I checked and ensure that there was no issue with the xml. I must have cleaned my projects more than n number of times. But the only thing that helped (and is now what I have started doing frequently when any of these errors pop up) is restarting Eclipse. Sometime the error goes in one restart, sometimes two.

Even though this restarting has helped me most of the time (almost all), it is at times very frustrating as I loose good amount of time because of it. So I want help to find some solution here.

Note: My Eclipse says version (Android DDMS - 22.6.2.v201403212031-1085508). Also this has occurred for different projects so I do not think that this should be code specific (I may b dumb for this point). (Also the log cat doesn't point to any specific part of the Projects apart from a **red** highligt error)

Comment: I don't think there's any way to fix these problems. Had them for years and probably will have them for years. Consider switching to Android Studio.

Comment: Have you considered switching to Android Studio?

Comment: missing R is because the other errors prevent your projects building, so focus on the other issues instead. One thing I can see is you are one version behind on Android DDMS - mine is 22.6.3.v201404151837-1123206. Otherwise, try manually deleting bin & gen folders - sometimes "clean" breaks.

Comment: This is not an answer, that's why I am posting a comment: I was a big fan of Eclipse, but after tried Android Studio just for a few hours I find out that it's way better than Eclipse (Android Studio is still beta) and not to forget that it is for developing on android. And if you start using gradle your life will be easier.

Comment: Unfortunately the same always happened for me as well, never could find a fix. I moved to Android Studio (and I also use IntelliJ IDEA). I actually PREFER IntelliJ as it is more mature (Android Studio is based off of IntelliJ, but still beta). I will never use Eclipse again.

Comment: @myanimal I tried once but it didnt seem that smooth m ay be I was not open to change. I will definitely give it a try now. Thanks for the help. :)

Comment: @RichardLeMesurier Actually I did upgrade Eclipse once and it just bursted at almost every step. Even auto suggest stopped working then I upgraded to this version and its a bit statble. Dont know wats comes with the next update but will definitely try. Thanks :)

Comment: @Android-Developer Yes they are the next options it seems and as you say they are better I will definitely try them out. Does gradle need anything extra apart from normal coding practise? I will search meanwhile. Let me know your views. Thanks :)

Comment: @AtulOHolic I used gradle for first time after switching to Android Studio, I can't say that I know everything, but it seems much better way to handle dependencies, build system , build types and etc. You don't need anything specific for gradle at the beginning, you will learn everything you need during the development, but it's way better than anything which I used before.