# Eclipse error : button1 cannot be resolved or is not a field

Tags: java, android, eclipse

Here is my MainActivity.java code :

```
package com.dg.buttontest3;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener{
Button button;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    button = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
    button.setOnClickListener(this);
}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Log.d("dg","button was clicked");
}
}
```

And here is the activity_main.xml code :

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_marginLeft="18dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="18dp"
    android:text="Button" />
    </LinearLayout>
```

I am getting the following error while running this code on Eclipse ADT : button1 cannot be resolved or is not a field.
I don't understand what is wrong with my code. Please help.

Comment: put your activity_main .xml code here

Comment: did you clean and rebuild your project?

Comment: @StefanBeike Yes, I have cleaned and rebuild my project but result is same.

Comment: @sanatshukla , now have a look at it.

Comment: most likely related : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4842611/r-file-is-missing-android

Comment: Your code look good. where is your import for R ?

Comment: @sanatshukla, my R.java file is present in the gen folder so is it important to have it's import ? Actually I am a beginner in the Android with not much experience.

Comment: @sanatshukla I have added this statement in my MainActivity.java code : import com.dg.buttontest3.R; But still same result.

Comment: Clean and rebuild your project then try it

Comment: @DeepanshuGabba try removing android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true" these properties are not applicable in linear layout.

Comment: Linear layout ">" not available in your xml

Comment: Thanks @Amrut, it worked..code running successfully :)

Comment: @sanatshukla, I added it, no errors now.. thanks :)

Comment: @sanat shukla good eyes

Answer (score 1):

You haven't posted your XML code, but as this code seems to be working properly:

```
button = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
```

I'd guess that in your `activity_main.xml` you never create something called `button1`, or that you don't use the `@+id/` prefix.

It should look something like:

```
<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/button1"/>
```

Just realised something else, you need to change your `LinearLayout` opening tag so it has a `>`.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">
```

That might cause the button to never properly be recognised.

Comment: I have posted my xml code, can you look at it now ?

Comment: If you're still working on the main activity (i.e. just beginning) you could consider starting a new project from scratch to see if that fixes the issue. EDIT: might have found it